# Local variable in map task?

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to define a local variable in an inline reporter task with `map`?

This

```
to go
  show map [? * ?] [1 2 3]
end
```

displays `[1 4 9]`, as expected.  What's in the first set of brackets is a "reporter task".

What if I want to use `let` in the task?

```
to go
  show map [
             let sq ? * ?
             sq + 1
           ]
           [1 2 3]
end
```

Error: "Expected a reporter task here, rather than a list or block."  The entire first bracketed expression is highlighted as what's producing the syntax error.

Maybe I need to add the `task` keyword to tell NetLogo that this is a task?  The Programming Guide says that "the task primitive is optional" for `map` but it's worth a try.  This works:

```
to go
  show map (task [? * ?]) [1 2 3]
end
```

but this doesn't:

```
to go
  show map (task [
                   let sq ? * ?
                   sq + 1
                 ])
           [1 2 3]
end
```

The second instance of `sq` is highlighted, with the error message "Expected command."  It's odd the error is different this time.

Maybe I need to add `report`?

```
to go
  show map (task [
                   let sq ? * ?
                   report sq + 1
                 ])
           [1 2 3]
end
```

This is syntactically acceptable, but when I run it I get a runtime error: "MAP expected input to be a reporter task but got the command task (command task from: procedure GO) instead."

The only alternative I've found that works is to define a separate reporter:

```
to go
  show map square-plus-one [1 2 3]
end

to-report square-plus-one [n]
  let sq n * n
  report sq + 1
end
```

This's easy enough.  However, I'm curious whether there's something I'm missing.  Is there a way to use local variables in an inline reporter task?

Comment: I think reporter tasks with complex reporters are not possible in current version. See _Limitations_ section in [Programming Guide / Tasks](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks): _Reporter tasks can't contain commands, only a single reporter expression._

Comment: sadly, bergant is correct. see also https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/351

Comment: Thanks @bergant, SethTisue.  I missed that note in the Programming Guide.  I  github issue is definitive, and clarifies the situation.

Comment: bergant, @SethTisue, either of you want to post something like this the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reporter tasks with complex reporters are not currently possible. See the “Limitations” section in the Programming Guide, under "[Tasks](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks)":

> Reporter tasks can't contain commands, only a single reporter expression.

https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/351 is related — it specifically discusses the problem of needing to refer to a `?` variable from an outer scope.